# IE8 - 3 columns layout: 100% width, left and right div fixed width and 100% height + middle div min-width 955px

Tags: html, css, layout, height, width

I've to migrate an Sharepoint 2007 site to Sharepoint 2010 and users have the IE8 browser.

So, i would like to set the web site with that layout in cross browser mode.

My real problem is that I would set a gradient background to left and right columns with a 100% browser height and my middle `div` must have a min-width of 955px.

Is it possible without `TABLE` tag?

I tried:

```
<div id="main1">
   <div id="main2">
    <div id="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="right">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="middle">
         <table width="100%" height="500"> <tr><td>aaa</td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body,html{
     height:100%;
     min-height:100%;
     background-color:gray;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
}
#main1 {
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;

MIN-WIDTH: 995px;
border-bottom:1px solid gray;

height: auto;
min-height:100%


}
#main2 {
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
BACKGROUND: url(blue.gif) repeat-y right top;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
}
#left {
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
WIDTH: 20px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
background-color:blue;
FLOAT: left;
FONT-SIZE: 80%;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
height:100%;
}
#right {
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
MARGIN: 0px;
PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
WIDTH: 20px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
background-color:blue;
FLOAT: right;
FONT-SIZE: 80%;
PADDING-TOP: 0px;
height:100%;
}
#middle {
MARGIN: 0px 20px;
BACKGROUND: red;
FONT-SIZE: 80%;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
.cleaner {
HEIGHT: 1px;
CLEAR: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes,

```
<aside class="sidebar left"></aside>
<div class="mainContent"></div>
<aside class="sidebar right></asdie>
```

The rest is CSS. `<aside></aside>` is a HTML5 tag.
Have fun.

Comment: It works in ie8 with html5.js Besides that we are in 2013 there's no good reason to use anything xhtml 1.0 compatible.... :) just saying. Do however you think is best for you project.

Comment: Sorry but i've to develop an SharePoint 2010 site with that directive.

Answer (score 0):

As the standard screen resolution is 1024*768, you can give fixed width to left and right divs separately and also to the middle div.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. However I found the solution for adaptable widths, but my question remain to set the left and right columns as 100% browser width to give them a gradient background

Comment: for gradient background you can refer to this link. http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="mainContainer">

    <div id="left-column" class="column">           
    </div>

    <div id="middle-column" class="column">             
    </div>

    <div id="right-column" class="column">      
    </div>  

</div>
```

css

```
#mainContainer{
    width: 1355px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.column{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#middle-column{
    width: 955px;

}
#left-column, #right-column{
    width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: 955 is awfully wide though...wouldn't recommend a 3column page with 955 being the middle column width

Comment: In ie 8 does not work, neither setting --> body, html{height:100%;}

Comment: yes for 955... i'm trying to set the middle at 955 and left/right cols with 20, for a total sum of 995px

Comment: thats because you need to change your doctype to strict.

like this for instance
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: I can't change the doctype: i'm working with a SharePoint 2010 website and IE8 users browser